# How to carry on credential Cookies in XHR

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies, xmlhttprequest

So here is the situation:

Background: I am developing a Chrome App (not extension) using javascript making XHR calls to a website.

On login, I am posing all the form data (username, password etc.) to the login url like this

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("POST", 'http://somewebsite/Login.aspx', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.withCredentials = true;  
xhr.onload = function (e) {

    console.log('on load of login request');
    console.log(xhr);

    xhr.open('GET', 'http://somewebsite/STS/sts_default.asp', true);
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.responseType = 'document';
    xhr.onload = LogicFunction;

    xhr.send();

};
var params = "txtUsername=user&txtPassword=password"
xhr.send(params);
```

What I assume is that once the login request get processed, while I am using the same xhr object it should use the cookies that been set from the previous response.

While actually what happened is the l/login.aspx gives me a 302 redirect. And on that redirection its using the credential cookies. while the xhr I initiated within the onload block doesn't have any cookie credentials thus get kicked out by server.

What should I do to carry this cookie credentials.

Thanks

Comment: I have come across this issue a few times when building applications to interact with websites/web-services requiring logins in Visual Basic .NET and PHP. In those situations, I had to prevent the redirect, read the response headers, and save the "Set-Cookie" headers. In Javascript, I cannot remember the exact way this is done, but I would presume the basic idea is the same. Intercept the HTTP 3XX response code, read the headers, save the cookies, and send a GET to the Location header from the 3XX Redirect along with the cookies. Still, I am not 100% sure that this is possible with XHR.

Comment: Thanks Spencer, you are correct. I think it is not possible to set the cookies in XHR. But I would be very interested to know if it could be carry on with some technique. For example, when working with the chrome extension I don't have such problems at all.

Comment: I have checked from other resources that you will not be able to override the default behaviour of XHR redirection. How did you achieve that? Any hint, please?

Comment: VB.NET, PHP, Java, and most languages have different HTTP Request restrictions/rules compared to Javascript. So, in those languages, I was able to set specific flags to disable following redirections. For example, in PHP, I could set the CURL flag/option `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to false, and in VB.NET I could set the `AllowAutoRedirect` flag/option to false. One thing you might be able to try would be POSTing to an invisible iFrame. That would, in theory, set the cookies in the browser. That would not give you access to read the cookies, but the browser might include them on future AJAX.

Comment: Another possibility would be pseudo-proxying through a backend script on your server. So, for example, if you were using PHP, you would AJAX to your server something like: `/backend/proxy_request.php?action={URL of Page to Access}&method=POST` with a POST body of `payload=txtUsername%3Duser%26txtPassword%3Dpassword`. Then your script would cURL to *action* with the *method* as the request type, and the cURL request would send `$_POST['payload']` as its POST body. Once the request is received, your backend script would JSON encode the contents and dump them back for your JavaScript to handle.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions Spancer. I really appreciate for what you have done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Guys. The way how I did to keep the cookies are right. The browser (at least in chrome) helps to keep all the cookies that set by server. The only problem that I have was a 302 redirection, which actually was solved by a session transfer that is specific to this problem. So if you are reading this answer I can tell the way I did to preserve cookie information in the question is correct and still thank you for all those put effort and thought on this question.

Thanks